# Both my HTTP and HTTPS version of website are available in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google, https, http

I had recently done some changes to my SSL for my website, but eventually 2 versions of my website came up in Google Search Console, you can check in images:

[image: Console screenshot of HTTP and HTTPS variant]

One was HTTP   another  is HTTPS]. Now both of them are getting in SERPs but HTTPS variant is dominant.

Should I ignore the HTTP variant in Console or should I just keep it there. Another question is that the HTTPS variant does not have "WWW" in the URL is that hurting me SEO anyways?

Comment: http will not be popular much longer as browsers are tightening up.  I would just redirect to https.  Its your choice how you want to present your url.  I am doing the equivalent of **travelmykashmir.com**  It is easier for the user.  All the redirection can be done in htaccess if you are using apache or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions of the site will continue to be listed as two different sites
Search Console regards HTTP and HTTPS resources as different, so the data on them does not match. If your site uses both protocols, you should add two resources to Search Console.
The timing of the transfer of the site is not known, it will all depend on what the speed of scanning and how voluminous the site
Regarding the www:
Was there a version of the site with a www on the http version?
I just think that it is necessary to make a similar redirect to comply with the parameter, as it was before the move to https protocol
In general I try to make a redirect from the www version to the www-free version for the users' satisfaction, but here it all depends on the situation of each webmaster